# windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" causes problems with custom keyboard layout

Tags: android, keyboard, custom-keyboard

I'm developing a custom keyboard and would like to add a `TextView` above the keyboard to show what the user already has typed or suggestions for words he could want to type.

To do that I have the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
        android:id="@+id/keyboard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:keyPreviewLayout="@layout/preview"
        android:keyBackground="@drawable/key_background"
        android:background="@color/color_primary"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/keyboard"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/color_primary_dark"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="some sample text"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and the following code at the `InputMethodService`:

```
public class FancyInputMethodService extends InputMethodService {
    @Override
    public View onCreateInputView() {
        final RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard_layout, null);
        final KeyboardView keyboardView = (KeyboardView) layout.findViewById(R.id.keyboard);
        final Keyboard keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty);
        keyboardView.setKeyboard(keyboard);
        return layout;
    }
}
```

At a normal `EditText` at the top of the screen the keyboard looks fine and works well:

[image]

But if the `EditText` is in an `Activity` which uses the flag `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in the manifest, the keyboard view seems to cover the actual view instead of being transparent.

[image]

The left image shows the actual view with the soft keyboard closed, the image in the middle shows the weird behavior when the keyboard is open and the image on the right shows the default keyboard with the behavior I would expect.

I already tried to set the layouts background to transparent, but that didn't help.

The problem appears at several apps, e.g. WhatsApp, Hangouts, Facebook etc...Am I missing something or what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr

You are not using InputMethodService as intended, use the CandidateView framework instead.

Full answer:

1. Your keyboard layout should not include the text suggestions.
2. Override the InputMethodService#onCreateCandidatesView. It should look like this:

public View onCreateCandidatesView() {

```
    mYourView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.your_view, null);
    return mYourView;
}
```

3. When you want to show/hide your candidate view use setCandidatesViewShown(boolean show)